# Spring nested transaction causing high CPU usage

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-transactions

While processing thousands of batches (500 records in each batch) we found some high CPU usage and when we went through the code we found that we are using nested `@Transactional` annotation at some places and we thought this nested `@Transactional` could be the reason for the high peak.

But no where on internet we didn't find any previous issue someone have faced related to high CPU usage and Nested Transaction

Again when we checked our code properly we found that @Transactinal annotation that we are using at child method - **Class2.java** is from `javax.transaction.Transactional` and @Transactinal we are using at parent method - **Class1.java** is from  `@org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional`

**Class1.java**

```
@org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional 
 public void transform() {
    for (...) {                  // loop to process each batch
      class2Obj.otherFunction();
    }
  }
```

**Class2.java**

```
  @javax.transaction.Transactional
  public void otherFunction() {
  }
```

What could be the reason, is high CPU usage is because of

1. Only because of nested @Transactional (regardless of whether we are mixing @Transactional from different classes or not)
2. Not because of nested @Transactional but because of mixing @Transactional from different classes
3. Not at all related to @Transactional maybe due to some other reason?

**Note:** The reason we are pointing out at @Transactional is because, when we process less batches let's say some 100 / 50 batches we are not seeking high cpu usage